# In an Espresso test, how can I wait for coroutines launch()ed by a scope from rememberCoroutineScope()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-espresso

My Android app is using Jetpack Compose. Inside one of my `@Composable` functions, I get a coroutine scope:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // ...
```

Then, I use it in one of my buttons' `onClick` to run a suspend function:

```
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            doThings()
        }
    }) {
        // ...
    }
}

suspend fun doThings() {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to do an Espresso test of the click's results. However, immediately after

```
onNode(/* ... */).performClick()
```

`doThings()` isn't done yet. I'd like to wait until `doThings()` finishes, without using `Thread.sleep()`, something like:

```
waitUntil { theThingsAreDone() }
```

Is there any way I can do this without putting the test code in my production code?

If I could replace `scope` in my test, then I could use one that incremented and decremented a `CountingIdlingResource`, thus making Espresso wait for it automatically. Passing `scope` as a parameter to `MyComposable` might give me that control, but then I'd lose the behavior of `rememberCoroutineScope()`. Can I modify `scope` in my test, while having it still follow the behavior of `rememberCoroutineScope()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`waitUntil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/ComposeTestRule#waitUntil(kotlin.Long,kotlin.Function0)) to wait a specified maximum amount of time until a [condition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#manual-sync-waituntil) is true. So you just need some sort of condition to check whether the async operation was finished.

```
testRule.waitUntil(1000) { myCondition }
```

If you have asynchronous functions in your `ViewModel` that you want to test, the only way I found to achieve it was as follows:

1.) Move your dispatcher definition into the function signature:

```
fun asyncOperation(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO) {
    viewModelScope.launch(coroutineContext) {
        // async operation...
    }
}
```

2.) Call the function as `runBlocking` to make sure that it was executed after you reach the next statement:

```
@Test
fun test_asyncOperation() {

    //...
    runBlocking { myViewModel.asyncOperation(coroutineContext) }
    //... 
    // Here, you can be sure that asyncOperation completed
}
```